# How to update through foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, foreach

I want to update data of form fields in database through foreach loop. I have two columns in test_table ID and Input. I have fetched data through while loop and also have printed the value. Now I want to update fetched value. Please give some guidance for this.

Here is my code,

```
$sql = "select * from test_table";

 if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
 {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         $inputResult[]=$row;


     }

 }  <form method="POST">    <input type="text" value=<?php
echo $inputResult[0]['Input']; ?> id="$inputResult[0]['ID']">        <input
type="submit" name="submit">    </form>         <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])
    {
    $input = $inputResult[];
    foreach($input as $inputs => $value)
        {
        $Sql = "update test_table set Input='$value' where = '$inputs'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    } ?>
```

Please let me know what errors have in my code ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: missing closing tags, dont know `id="$inputResult[0]['ID']"`, missing name attribute,, or if u want to check errors, please use php `Error_reporting()`

Comment: Sandeep, your code is confusing, try to explain what you want to achieve, for example, in your `<form` you have **only one** text input, and you fill it with the **first** item of the array `$inputResult`, but, at the bottom, you have a `foreach` to process all the items in the array, that's weird.

Comment: Mainly I have to update only one field ,i.e, Input Column in database. Please give me some guidance or instruction that I could update one field.

Answer (score 0):

Next solution is very specific to your problem. The input text is the **first** element in your form, so, in the PHP code, we can get the input's ID and the VALUE by accessing the first item in the array $_POST (changes are pointed by arrows `◄■■■`):

```
<?php
$sql = "select * from test_table";

if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $inputResult[]=$row;
    }
}
?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $inputResult[0]['Input'];?>"
                       name="<?php echo $inputResult[0]['ID'];?>" /> ◄■■■ NAME, NOT ID.
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $value = reset( $_POST ); // ◄■■■ FIRST VALUE IN $_POST (['input']).
    $id = key( $_POST ); // ◄■■■ FIRST KEY IN $_POST (['ID']).
    $Sql = "update test_table set Input='$value' where id='$id'"; // ◄■■■ $VALUE AND $ID.
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>
```

I replaced the attribute `id=` by `name=` in the input text, because PHP needs names, not ids.

After we get the first value and the first key, we can insert them into the sql string.

**Edit :**

Fixed the missing tags (oops!). I think I found the error, it's so little that it's hard to see : pay attention to next line:

```
     ▼
    $Sql = "update test_table set Input='$value' where id='$id'"; // ◄■■■ $VALUE AND $ID.
```

Do you see the variable on the left : `$Sql` (the first letter is uppercased). Now let's see the next line:

```
                         ▼
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

The same variable is not uppercased, once you fix that, everything works :

```
     ▼
    $sql = "update test_table set Input='$value' where id='$id'"; // ◄■■■ $VALUE AND $ID.
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                         ▲
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried above code but data is not updating in database. I think you also forgot the PHP tags in name attribute.

Comment: @SandeepKumar, fixed the missing tags and edited the answer to explain the error, check it out!